# Alignment within Dialog Input

Tags: alignment

I'd like to have different elements (checkboxes and input fields) aligned horizontally in a dialog box, but I can't figure out how to do it. The misalignment becomes more apparent when the list gets longer. Thanks!

[image: dialog box misaligned]

```
list = RandomWord["Noun", 20];
checkedSeries = {};
DialogInput[DialogNotebook[Pane[
    TextGrid[{{"Display?", "Rename"},
      {CheckboxBar[Dynamic[checkedSeries], list, 
        Appearance -> "Vertical", ImageMargins -> 5.],
       ResourceFunction["ListInputField"][Dynamic[list], String, 
        Length[list]]
       },
      {Button["Done", DialogReturn[1]], SpanFromLeft}}, 
     Spacings -> 2]
    , Scrollbars -> {True, True}]]];
```

Comment: For a robust solution I'd go with `{Checkbox[...], InputField[...]}` rows, so that they will be aligned automatically.

Comment: That make sense! Suggestions on how to make that work with "ListInputField"?